# How to change pager class to view

Tags: paging

I have HTML desing of pagger ,How to I assign my own class to pager in side view ?I dont have any idea about it so will you plese tell how can I ?

Comment: You could refer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41306/how-to-add-a-class-to-the-widget-pager-of-views-slideshow for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two ways you can do it:-

1. In template.php , you can use [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7). Then overrite it.
2. You can make a views template and overrite it. For this just goto advance option in views and search for template suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I could not find a way to add a class to `theme_pager()` using the `hook_preprocess_HOOK` system, so here is a slightly different `template.php` solution that won't involve having to override a core function.

I noticed that views pagers are also run through `theme_item_list()` which does allow you to add classes.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_item_list(&$vars) {
  $vars['attributes']['class'][] = 'my-class';
}
```

You can/should add an if condition check to see that the list really is going to be a pager, e.g. use `if ($vars['attributes']['class'][0] == 'pager')` or some other identifier to confirm that you're adding the class to a pager ul.